# Angular 2/4 rxjs combining observables. Alternative of Observable.combineAll()?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have a **form: BehaviorSubject(FormGroup)** and an **id: Subject(number)**.

On ngOnInit in component I want to combine and subscribe both of them and getting value of subscription even if `id: Subject` hasn't `next()'ed.`

I don't use `Observable.combineLatest` because I get no value from subscription while `id: Subject` makes any `next()`.

In RXJS there is solution: combineAll()! But in Angular 4 there is no such method.

So I updated package.json rxjs up to "rxjs": "^5.4.3". Now I can even take into this function in my IntelliJ, but browser telling me

> Observable.combineAll is not a function

Comment: Did you import it? I think the syntax is `import 'rxjs/add/operator/combineAll'`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the user had the wrong version of the library and noted such in an answer but deleted the answer so it still looks like an open question.

Comment: @Meir, yes, I did. My thread of developing even can see what is inside of 'combineAll', but cannot use it